# Topology carried over by a mapping of a topological space into a set.

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a mapping of a topological space $X$ into a set $Y$. Let $J$ be the topology on $X$. What exactly is "the topology carried over to $Y$ by $f$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [final topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology) determined by $f$: here the open sets of $Y$ are the subsets $V \subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. This satisfies a universal property: see Proposition 1.7.1 of [Schapira's notes](http://people.math.jussieu.fr/~schapira/lectnotes/Topo.pdf). Assuming you want $f$ to be continuous, this topology is as fine as it could be in the sense that it contains any topology which makes $f$ continuous.

If $f$ is surjective then we've just described the [quotient topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space) determined by $f$. I must admit that I can't think of any good examples in which this is not the case.

Comment: Would you be willing to give more context, by the way? We might be able to figure this out for sure, then.

Comment: Hi Dylan, i think its exactly what you explained. Can you explain a little bit what do you mean "as fine as it can be"?

Comment: A topology gets "finer" the more open sets it has. If there were any open sets in $Y$ besides those already described, $f$ wouldn't be continuous.

Comment: Exactly, I claim that any topology on $Y$ for which $f$ is continuous is contained in this one.

Comment: Actually, I found a more common term for it. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

That topology consists of exactly the subsets $U\subseteq Y$ for which $f^{-1}(U) \in J$, that is $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

One should also emphasise the *universal property*: with the final topology on $Y$, if $Z$ is a topological space, then  a function $g:Y \to Z$ is continuous if and only if the composition $gf$ is continuous. Many constructions in general topology are designed to enable the construction of continuous functions. The final topology is also called the *identification topology* in the case $f$ is surjective.

Dually, there is an *initial topology*  for $f:X \to Y$ if now $X$ is a set, and $Y$ is a topological space.